# Mapbox Geocoder seems to center in the incorrect location for New York City addresses

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-js

I'm using https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/mapbox-gl-geocoder/

```
map.addControl(new mapboxgl.Geocoder());
```

But when I try New York City addresses the map centers on an incorrect location.

I expect the address to be the center of the map when the map relocates.

But I see that it is incorrect, sometimes by a lot

For example, for "1 Broadway, New York, NY" I see  (1 Broadway is not even viewable without panning and zooming)

Is there a better geocoder example that works correctly for NYC addresses?

[image]

BUT the correct map is something like this:

[image]

It seems to work in other locations

Moscone Center SF (correct)

[image]

Whitehouse (correct)

[image]

Comment: This actually looks like an issue with the mapbox-gl-geocoder control itself choosing to fitBounds if it exists and not address deep results that also contain bounds information. I've filed an issue for this on the project page here: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder/issues/23 Thanks!

Comment: @tristen Thanks for filing the issue!